# Google Authentication Email Scope using Firebase

Tags: firebase, polymer

I am using the Firebase Polymer Component to get users to login using Google Oauth. I cannot though seem to find a way to get their email addresses. I cannot seem to be able to add email to scope.

There seems to be an issue in Github regarding the element with this.

https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/firebase-element/issues/39

I used firebase-auth polymer element and added the email scope. I have also created an element called hi9-login with this in.

https://github.com/HackITtoday/hi9-login

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../firebase-element/firebase-auth.html">
<link rel="import" href="../firebase-element/firebase-document.html">
<link rel="import" href="../paper-button/paper-button.html">

<dom-module id="hi9-login">
  <template>
    <firebase-auth id="firebaseLogin" user="{{user}}" status-known="{{statusKnown}}" location="https://hi9site.firebaseio.com" provider="google" on-error="errorHandler" on-user-created="userSuccessHandler" on-password-changed="userSuccessHandler" on-password-reset="userSuccessHandler" on-user-removed="userSuccessHandler"></firebase-auth>
    <!--  <firebase-document location="https://hi9site.firebaseio.com/data" id="firebaseDocument"></firebase-document> -->
    <firebase-document location="{{userDataUrl}}" data="{{userData}}" id="firebaseUser"></firebase-document>
    <firebase-document location="{{ownerDataUrl}}" data="{{ownerData}}" id="firebaseOwner"></firebase-document>
    <paper-button on-tap="logout" hidden$="{{computeLogoutHidden(statusKnown, user)}}"> Logout </paper-button>
    <paper-button on-tap="login" hidden$="{{computeLoginHidden(statusKnown, user)}}"> Login </paper-button>
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  var that = {};
  Polymer({
    is: 'hi9-login',
    properties: {
      params: {
        scope: "email"
      },
      provider: {
        type: String, value: 'anonymous'
      },
      message: {
        type: String, value: ''
      },
      email: {
        type: String, value: ''
      },
      password: {
        type: String, value: ''
      },
      user: {
        type: Object, value: null,
        notify: true
      },
      uid: {
        computed:'returnVal(user.uid)'
      },
      owner: {
        computed:'returnVal(user.owner)'
      },
      userDataUrl:{
        computed:'getUserDataUrl(uid)'
      },
      ownerDataUrl:{
        computed:'getOwnerDataUrl(owner, uid)'
      },
      statusKnown: {
        type: Boolean
      },
      show_model: {
        type: Boolean, notify: true,
        computed: "computeLogoutHidden(statusKnown, user)"
      },
      role: {
        computed: 'getRole(user,userData)',
        notify: true
      },
      admin: {
        computed: 'isAdmin(role)',
        notify: true
      }
    },
    returnVal: function(val) {
      if (val !== undefined && val !== null) {
        return val;
      } else {
        return undefined;
      }
    },
    getOwnerDataUrl: function(owner,uid) {
      return "https://hi9site.firebaseio.com/owner/" + owner + "/users/" + uid;
    },
    getUserDataUrl: function(uid) {
      that = this;
      setTimeout(function(){ that.whenReady(); }, 7000);
      return "https://hi9site.firebaseio.com/users/" + uid;
    },
    login: function() {
      var params;
      try {
        params = JSON.parse(this.params);
      } catch (e) {
        params = null;
      }
      if (this.provider == 'password') {
        params = params || {};
        params.email = this.email;
        params.password = this.password;
      }
      this.$.firebaseLogin.login(params);
      this.log("Login");
    },
    logout: function() {
      this.log("Logout");
      this.$.firebaseLogin.logout();
    },
    errorHandler: function(e) {
      this.log("Login Status");
      this.message = 'Error: ' + e.detail.message;
    },
    userSuccessHandler: function(e) {
      this.log("Login Status");
      this.message = e.type + ' success!';
    },
    createUserHandler: function(e) {
      this.log("createUserHandler");
      this.$.firebaseLogin.createUser(this.email, this.password);
    },
    changePasswordHandler: function(e) {
      this.log("changePasswordHandler");
      this.$.firebaseLogin.changePassword(this.email, this.password, this.newPassword);
    },
    resetPasswordHandler: function(e) {
      this.log("resetPasswordHandler");
      this.$.firebaseLogin.sendPasswordResetEmail(this.email);
    },
    computePasswordHidden: function(provider) {
      this.log("Login Status");
      return provider !== 'password';
    },
    computeCreateUserDisabled: function(email, password) {
      this.log("computeCreateUserDisabled");
      return !email || !password;
    },
    computeChangePasswordDisabled: function(email, password, newPassword) {
      this.log("computeChangePasswordDisabled");
      return !email || !password || !newPassword;
    },
    computeResetPasswordDisabled: function(email, password) {
      this.log("computeResetPasswordDisabled");
      return !email || !password;
    },
    computeRemoveUserDisabled: function(email, password) {
      this.log("computeRemoveUserDisabled");
      return !email || !password;
    },
    computeLoginHidden: function(statusKnown, user) {
      this.log("computeLoginHidden");
      return !statusKnown || !!user;
    },
    computeLogoutHidden: function(statusKnown, user) {
      this.log("computeLogoutHidden");
      return !statusKnown || !user;
    },
    computeLoginStatus: function(statusKnown, user) {
      var d = new Date();
      var n = d.getTime();

      this.log("Login Status");

      if (statusKnown && user) {
        return 'Logged in';
      }
      if (statusKnown) {
        return 'Logged out';
      }
      return 'Unknown (checking status...)';
    },
    log: function(log) {
//      var d = new Date();
//      var n = d.getTime();
//      this.$.firebaseDocument.query.ref().push({log: log,time:n,user:this.user});
    },
    getRole: function(user, userData) {
      if (userData !== undefined && userData !== null && user !== null) {
        if (this.userSet === undefined && userData.owner === undefined) { // Stops Looping.
          this.userSet = true;
          if (userData.num === undefined ) {
            userData.num = prompt("Hi "+user.google.displayName+"\nPlease tell me your mobile phone number?", "07");
          }
          if (userData.owner === undefined) {
            userData.owner = prompt("What is your housing association?", "Yarlington");
          }
          if (userData.email === undefined) {
            userData.email = prompt("and lastly you email address?", "");
          }
          if (userData.log === undefined) {
            var d = new Date();
            var n = d.getTime();
            userData.log = [{first: n}]
          }
          userData.user = user;
          this.userData = clone(userData);
          this.ownerData = clone(userData);
        }
        // user
        if (!userData.hasOwnProperty("role")) {
          userData.role = "User"
        }
        return userData.role;
      } else {
        return 'no data'
      }
    },
    isAdmin: function(role) {
      return role = 'admin';
    },
    whenReady: function() {
      var userDataTest = clone(this.$.firebaseUser.data);
      delete(this.$.firebaseUser.data);
      if (userDataTest === undefined || userDataTest === null){
        userDataTest = {placeholder:true}
      };
      this.$.firebaseUser.data = userDataTest;
      var ownerDataTest = clone(this.$.firebaseOwner.data);
      delete(this.$.firebaseOwner.data);
      if (ownerDataTest === undefined || ownerDataTest === null){
        ownerDataTest = {placeholder:true}
      };
      if (this.ownerDataUrl) {
        this.$.firebaseOwner.data = ownerDataTest;
      }
    }
  });

  function clone(obj) {
    var copy;
    // Handle the 3 simple types, and null or undefined
    if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;
    // Handle Date
    if (obj instanceof Date) {
      copy = new Date();
      copy.setTime(obj.getTime());
      return copy;
    }
    // Handle Array
    if (obj instanceof Array) {
      copy = [];
      for (var i = 0, len = obj.length; i < len; i++) {
        copy[i] = clone(obj[i]);
      }
      return copy;
    }
    // Handle Object
    if (obj instanceof Object) {
      copy = {};
      for (var attr in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = clone(obj[attr]);
      }
      return copy;
    }
    throw new Error("Unable to copy obj! Its type isn't supported.");
  }
</script>
```

Here also is a screenshot in JSFiddle showing it's not working

[image]

Comment: Did you try writing some code? If so, share it here. If not, write some code and then share it here : )

Comment: Of course. I created an element with the firebase-auth element inside it. Then added the scope email. Here is the link to the repo https://github.com/HackITtoday/hi9-login

Answer (score 3):

You can add a scope to the [authWithOAuthRedirect](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/google.html) API.

For example,

```
  ref.authWithOAuthRedirect('google', errorHandler, {
    scope: "email"
  });
```

Then, in your [onAuth](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/onauth.html) handler you can get the "authData.google.email" property:

```
  ref.onAuth(function(authData) {
  if (authData) {
    console.log("Authenticated with email: ", authData.google.email);
  } else {
    console.log("Client unauthenticated.")
  }
});
```

Comment: I have added the code and the ref to firebase-auth. This might be where the issue is.

Comment: Looking at your "login" method, I would use dev tools to step through the code, following it through to the firebaseLogin.login(params) call and step through the firebase-auth handler to make sure it's passing a valid JSON object with a scope property to ref.authWithOAuthRedirect.  It could be some problem with converting between strings in JSON and a true JavaScript Object.

Comment: Done that and there seems to be an issue with this element and just this problem in Github. I have added a link in my question. Might try forking and then adding the work around. Not very satisfactory.